# SCSS Interpolation for stateement

Tags: sass

I am wanting to have the ability to create 10 classes for my stylesheet without having to create each one in case I decide I need more over time. I obviously don't have this correct and need some help on what I am doing wrong.

```
@mixin ladders($num) {
 @for $num from 1 to 10 {
  .ladder-#{$num} {
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
 }
}
```

I have looked over the reference material and still and having a hard time grasping the total concept of putting it all together.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The problem is what?  A parse error?  What is the error?  Incorrect output?  What output did you expect? No output?

Comment: The problem is that I am not sure how I call this to make it output the 10 classes that I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your mixin will always produce 9 classes because you've hard coded your for loop for `1 to 10` (which excludes 10).  You need to write it like so:

```
@mixin ladders($num) {
    @for $i from 1 through $num {
        .ladder-#{$i} {
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you just need to invoke it somewhere, it doesn't have to be inside of a selector if you don't want it to be.

```
@include ladders(5);
```

Output:

```
.ladder-1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.ladder-2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.ladder-3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.ladder-4 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.ladder-5 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```